# Detect whether a stationary cursor is hovering over a previously hidden, now visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

### Description:

As a continuation (or perhaps rephrasing) of my previous question, I'm attempting to detect whether the cursor is over a previously hidden, now-faded-in element without actually moving the cursor to do it.

Here's the setup: Leave the mouse completely still while an element is faded in underneath it. Once the fade-in animation completes, a script should detect that the newly revealed element is in fact beneath the cursor and then fire off a mouse event via `jQuery.trigger()` or some such.

In the Fiddle provided below, the red box merely indicates where one should place their cursor; it is not otherwise to be utilized. Perhaps most importantly, I want to know whether it is possible to accomplish this task **without tracking mouse coordinates.**

### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xw8Z/7/

### Code:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    //Fades in the element
    $('#kitty').fadeIn('slow', function() {

        //This verifies that the element exists
        if ($('#kitty').length != 0) {

          //Do something to detect that #kitty is underneath the mouse cursor

        }

    });

}, 3000);

$('#kitty').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

Basically, you set a data parameter on the element you want to check for the mouse hovering, and then look at that parameter when it's time to check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xw8Z/8/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#kitty').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        if ($('#kitty').length != 0) {
          if($('#kitty').data("hovering") == "yes")
          {
              //Take whatever your intended action is
              alert("hovering");
          }
        }
    });
}, 3000);

$('#kitty').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });

    //Set the data parameter
    $(this).data("hovering","yes");

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });

    //Unset the parameter when the mouse leaves
    $(this).data("hovering","");
});
```

Comment: This would be an amazing solution but it does not work Chrome 36 or Internet Explorer 11+; only Firefox 31.